# Should an obese 16 year old male cut calories?

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition, calories, nutrition-information

I am 16, Male, 250 pounds, and am at a body fat percentage of 34%. At this point I'm considering cutting calories and consuming only 1900 calories since it is 500 calories below my TDEE as well as eating as clean as I can, and if I follow it strictly I should be able to lose 1 pound a week. I may also consider cardio. The only trouble here is that I'm not sure if it will hinder my natural growth. I would get in touch with a doctor but I my parents aren't willing to do so since we have financial issues.

Also, are there any good fat loss communities on here? I don't use this site
often.

EDIT: Also, I forgot to mention. My height is **5'8**

Comment: How tall are you?

Comment: This is a Q&A forum, it's not really suitable if you're looking for a fat loss community. If you have any questions, feel free to post on here, otherwise, you may find http://www.reddit.com/r/fitness helpful, as well as the links on there to other various sub-reddits. Good luck!

Comment: You should get your hormone levels checked, at your age and height 250 lbs is way above normal.

Comment: Get all the nutrition from vegetables/fruit that you can (kale most nutrient dense in world), your body will pull energy and calories from your fat stores. Have some variance with meat/fish/eggs if you can as well.  As long as you get a variety of foods and eat nutrient-dense foods like kale you should be ok.  Clean eating, good for you! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[At (250 lbs) 113kg you are obese.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index#/media/File:Body_mass_index_chart.svg) To lose weight you need to eat below the amount of calories you need for a day. Once you are 17 you are medically classified as an adult by most doctors and are heading towards the end of your growth (more so as a male).

Calorie restriction below 1500 is not recommended for any healthy male of any height and is the bottom limit. Your chosen limits sound sensible, I would still reassess every 6 months to make sure you don't plateau your weight loss.

Calorie restriction can in some cases still lead to underdevelopment, but its also worth considering that remaining obese in your teens has a very strong correlation with weight increase to morbidly obese in your yearly 20s.

Echoing the other answer, eating healthily is extremely important at your age, you need your vitamins and minerals to ensure you grow properly and 1900 calories is still plenty to ensure that you are properly nourished.

As with all "pure advice" you should seek the comment of a doctor before taking on a diet.

Comment: Sounds good. Also, should I try to do strength training along with this? I know I probably wont be able to build muscle but I'm not sure if it'll aid me in fat loss and if Ill gain much strength from doing it.

Comment: I would bet you that you will be able to increase your muscle mass with this diet, however only if you are total new to the gym, your muscles are going to reach a plateau where you will need to bulk. But if you havent touches the weights yet, its possible with the right nutrients to build muscle and grow at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Hey don't cut the calories. Cut the calorie chase!! :)

Try to eat clean - Chuck out any store brought items. Try preparing meals from scratch. Eat lots of lean protein. Balance carbs, protein and fats. 
don't measure weight, measure fat %.

Do strength training along with Cardio. I have never known that physical activity hinders natural growth.  Eat hard and play hard!